# ERROR: Cannot convert type System.type to system.drawing.Image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image, datagridview

I have two forms: one is `equipmentfinder` and the other is `productdescription`. I have a datagridview with columns `productname` and `productimage` in `equipmentfinder` form.

When I click on one of the column (i.e.) `productimage` column it will go to another page that was working fine.

I am making WinForms application.

But I want to display the selected productimage in `productimage` column from datagridview in another picturebox in `equipmentfinder` form.

So for that I have done like this:

```
 private void productGridview_Cellclick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == productgridview.Columns["productimage"].Index)
    {
        ProductDescriptionForm pf = new ProductDescriptionForm();
        pf.ShowDialog(this);
    }
 }
```

and in `productdescription` form I have done like this:

```
 private void ProductDescriptionForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    EquipmentFinder eqipu = new EquipmentFinder();
    this.imagepicture.Image = (Image)eqipu.productgridview.SelectedCells.GetType();
 }
```

but I got an error at this line:

```
this.imagepicture.Image =(Image)eqipu.productgridview.SelectedCells.GetType();
```

> Error: cannot convert type system.type To system.drawing.image

Comment: GetType gives you the Type of the cell, not the contents of the cell as a type.  You might want to try dropping the GetType() bit and just casting the SelectedCell to an image (or the item within the cell)

Comment: how to do that would you pls help...

Comment: @tony would you pls help on this ...

Comment: Sorry for the delay, see James' response below which explains what I was saying much better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are **trying** to retrieve here is the type of the object stored in the datagridview cell, which is indeed a "System.Type" object and not a "System.Drawing.Image", casting it is of no use here. You need to get the content of the cell, not the content's type.

There are other errors in this code!

- SelectedCells is a collection of cells. So you aren't getting the type of a cell's content, but the type of the collection (ie DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection). If you are sure at least one cell is selected, you should use `SelectedCells[0]`.
- You want to retrieve the content of the cell, not its type. Use `Value`instead of `GetType()`.
- I don't understand why you instantiate a new `EquipmentFinder`. This will create an empty and never displayed form... What I suggest: create a property to hold the image in `ProductDescriptionForm`:

  ```
  public Image Picture
  {
      get { return imagepicture.Image; }
      set { imagepicture.Image = value; }
  }
  ```

Then set this property before displaying the product description form:

```
    private void productGridview_Cellclick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.ColumnIndex == productgridview.Columns["productimage"].Index)
      {
          ProductDescriptionForm pf = new ProductDescriptionForm();
          pf.Picture = (Image)productgridview.SelectedCells[0].Value;
          pf.ShowDialog(this);
      }
   }
```

And remove the code you've written in `ProductDescriptionForm_Load`.

PS: though I hope this code works, it is still missing boundaries and type checking. I would recommend writing something like this:

```
    private void productGridview_Cellclick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
      // Don't handle clicks on the column header.
      if (e.RowIndex == -1) return; 

      // Bad index
      if (e.ColumnIndex != productgridview.Columns["productimage"].Index) return;

      // No selection
      if (productgridview.SelectedCells.Count == 0) return;

      // Make sure we have an image in this cell.
      object selectedValue = productgridview.SelectedCells[0].Value;
      if (selectedValue is Image) 
      {
          // Forms are IDisposable, so use them embedded in a using statement.
          using (ProductDescriptionForm pf = new ProductDescriptionForm())
          {
              pf.Picture = (Image)selectedValue;
              pf.ShowDialog(this);
          }
      }
   }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey Odalet I got an error at this line pf.picture= (Image)productgridview.SelectedCells[0].Value;                       like   this Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Drawing.Image'.

Comment: That means the selected cell doesn't contain an image but an integer. Where are you clicking? On the cell that contains the image?

Comment: do i need to set any on ProductDescriptionForm  load event

Comment: Well... I've reproduced this behavior by clicking on the column header. If I click on the cell, everything goes well. You could test whetheryoun are clicking the column header or a content cell (e.RowIndex == -1) I'll edit the post to include this test.

Comment: I have to quit now, but I've crafted a little example of what I suppose you're trying to achieve. You can download a Visual Studio 2008 solution demonstrating this here (tell me when you get this so that I remove it from my dropbox account): 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14708294/WindowsFormsApplication1.zip

Comment: Hi odalet I have uploaded your image i have failed at this condition                                                 if (selectedValue is Image)
            {
                // Forms are IDisposable, so use them embedded in a using statement.
                using (ProductDescriptionForm pf = new ProductDescriptionForm())
                {
                    pf.picture = (Image)selectedValue;
                    pf.ShowDialog(this);
                }
            }  the if condition returns false .... i dont know how it returns false.......

Comment: i am not defining columns to grid view in designer the data will be binding form database and image also..

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things. First, using GetType() gets the object type, not the object itself, so you need to remove the GetType(). Secondly, it looks like SelectedCells is a collection, so you would need to specify the cell index.

```
//replace zero index with index of the cell that contains the image
this.imagepicture.Image = (Image)eqipu.productgridview.SelectedCells[0];
```